# Devise::PasswordsController#new redirects to home instead of showing password reset form, routes.rb OK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I used the code of [a demo Devise app](https://github.com/holden/devise-omniauth-example), it works fine except password reset.

The first route of my `config/routes.rb` is `devise_for :users`

But somehow when I click "Forgot your password?" it redirects to home:

```
Started GET "/users/password/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-22 16:56:45 +0900
  Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
default_url_options is passed options: {}
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/
```

I don't have any file containing "PasswordsController" so I guess Rails uses [the one](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.2/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb) found in the Devise from my Gemfile: `gem 'devise', '~> 1.2.1'`

**QUESTION:** How can I make PasswordsController show the password reset form instead of redirecting to home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't let you recover your password if you are signed in. Try logging out and then re-try the forgot password path.

I literally just dealt with this same issue, and it seemed to be the fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How did I not realize that? The page shows fine once logged out.